# How to control the "flow" of an ASP.NET MVC (3.0) web app that relies on Facebook membership, with Facebook C# SDK?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, facebook-c#-sdk

I want to totally remove the standard ASP.NET membership system and use Facebook only for my web app's membership. *Note, this is not a Facebook canvas app question.*

Typically, in an ASP.NET app you have some key properties & methods to control the "flow" of an app. Notably: `Request.IsAuthenticated`, `[Authorize]` (in MVC apps), `Membership.GetUser()` and `Roles.IsUserInRole()`, among others. It looks like `[FacebookAuthorize]` is equivalent to `[Authorize]`. Is `fbApp.Session != null` essentially the same as `Request.IsAuthenticated`?

Also, there's some standard work I do across all controllers in my site. So I built a BaseController that overrides `OnActionExecuting(FilterContext)`. Typically, I populate ViewData with the user's profile within this action. Would performance suffer if I made a call to `fbApp.Get("me")` in this action?

I use the Facebook Javascript SDK to do registration, which is nice and easy. But that's all client-side, and I'm having a hard time wrapping my mind around when to use client-side facebook calls versus server-side. There will be a point when I need to grab the user's facebook uid and store it in a "profile" table along with a few other bits of data. That would probably be best handled on the return url from the registration plugin... correct?

On a side note, what data is returned from `fbApp.Get("me")`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Facebook C# SDK provides an action filter called [FacebookAuthorize] that will handle the authentication like you describe. And yes, fbApp.Request == null is the correct way to determine if the user is authenticated. I think I'll add a property on the next release called IsAuthenticated to make it easier.

You are correct in using the Javascript SDK for login. Basically, how it works is the Javascript side creates the cookie that FacebookApp reads and verifies. For a non-canvas app you basically have to use the Javascript SDK. You could do it all manually with OAuth, but that would be a huge pain.

And regarding the result of fbApp.Get("me") the result is a JsonObject. You can access it two ways:

```
// Using dynamic (.Net 4.0 only)
var app = new FacebookApp();
dynamic me = app.Get("me");
string firstName = me.first_name;
string lastName = me.last_name;
string email = me.email;

// Using IDictionary<string, object> (.Net 3.5, .Net 4.0, WP7)
var app = new FacebookApp();
var me = (IDicationary<string,object>)app.Get("me");
string firstName = (string)me["first_name"];
string lastName = (string)me["last_name"];
string email = (string)me["email"];
```

We have more code samples on our [Codeplex wiki](http://facebooksdk.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Code%20Examples).

Comment: Thanks Nathan, that helps a lot. Couple things: you said, fbApp.Request == null. Did you mean fbApp.Session? From a performance perspective, fbApp.Get("me") makes a call to facebook every time it's run right? Is there a way to just grab the user's facebook id from their session? I'd like to avoid hitting facebook on every request by caching their info in a profile table on my db - then rely on fbApp.Session == true for making sure they're logged in. Is that the common scenario?

Comment: Couple more ?'s. What's going on in the FacebookApp() constructor? It does something to get the user's session. My guess is it handles the cookie/token/oauth2 process. How does it impact performance?

Comment: Nevermind, did some debugging... turns out the facebookId IS in the cookie! Nice. Now I only need to use fbApp.Get("me") the first time they connect. From then on, realtime updates can keep my data fresh for the user.